# how to find limit of $\lim_{n\to+\infty}\int_0^{+\infty}|f(x+\frac1n)-f(x)|dx$?

Tags: analysis, integration

Assume $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$ and $\int_0^{+\infty}|f(x)|dx\lt+\infty$. Then how does one find $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\int_0^{\infty}\left|f\!\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right)-f(x)\right|dx?$$

Thanks for any hint

Comment: Do you mean $\lim_{n\to\infty}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Show that for each $A>0$ and $n\geqslant 1$, $\int_A^{+\infty}\left|f\left(x+\frac 1n\right)-f(x)\right|dx\leqslant 2\int_{A-1}^{+\infty}f(x)dx$.
2. So the problem remains to determine the limit of $\int_0^A\left|f\left(x+\frac 1n\right)-f(x)\right|dx$ as $n\to +\infty$ for $A>0$. Use uniform continuity.